# React-Router - Can i get the next path string in browser history of react router or check if there is somthing forward?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron, browser-history

I'm making an application on Electron with React, and i want to replicate the functionality of navegation in the browser.

I have a goBack and goForward button, and i want to disable the goForward when there is nothing on next and disable the goBack when there is nothgin on back, just like the browsers do it.

So i have react-router, im doint that with

`browserHistory.goBack()
browserHistory.goForward()`

So i want a way to detect that is nothig next and disable the button. Can be geeting the next and back path string or checking if there is something.